# How to save token in database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a class User with:

```
int id;
String username;
String password; 
String token; 
Date tokenExpires;
```

And i have a method like this:

```
private EntityManager em;
    private User authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        // Authenticate against a database, LDAP, file or whatever
        // Throw an Exception if the credentials are invalid

        Query query = em.createQuery("Select u from User u WHERE u.username = :name and u.password = :password");
        query.setParameter("name", username);
        query.setParameter("password", password);
        return (User) query.getSingleResult();      
    }
```

and a method to generate a token:

```
    private String issueToken(String username) {
        Random random = new SecureRandom();
        String token = new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
        return token;
}
```

how to save this token to db, everytime user log in? so when user log in should generate a token, if user log in again it should generate a new token

Answer (score 0):

When a user logs in, simply fetch the user from the database, then set the mentioned fields, the token and its' expiration date:

```java
public User updateUser(String username, String password) {
    User user = getUserBy(username, password);
    String token = issueToken();
    // token expires in 30 mins;
    Date tokenExpires = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1800000);
    user.setToken(token);
    user.setTokenExpires(tokenExpires);
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.merge(user);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Considering you are using Hibernate, then, the User model has to be annotated as well:

```java
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String token;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date tokenExpires;

    // getters and setters, make sure they are present
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you use spring, try this guide, for example: https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-oauth2-jdbc-token-store-example/